# Get most recent index value, which is available in both ZOO objects

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

For example, I have two ZOO objects:

```
x <- zoo(matrix(1:10, 10, 2), 1:10)
y <- zoo(matrix(11:20, 10, 2), 5:15)
```

I want to get first index value, which have both ZOO objects. In this example it must be index value of 5. Because index of 5 have both objects and this is most recent index.

I can loop index(x) vector and with inner loop compare every index(y) element with index(x) elements, but this looks ugly. Can i do that without looping? Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I found that I can do following:

```
idx_val <- head(intersect(index(x), index(y)), 1)
```

This is clear and fast solution? If yes, then question is closed.

Comment: That seems like a good solution.  Here is another one `index(na.omit(merge(x, y)))[1]` .   Note that it differs in the case that there are leading NAs in `x` and `y` so which one to use would depend on what you want.

Comment: Yes, I need to remove leading NAs, so your variant is better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have transferred this from comment to here and improved slightly.  This approach differs from the one posted in the question in the case that there are leading NA values in `x` or `y` :

```
start(na.omit(merge(x, y)))
```